# Refresh to Car Position Correct Way Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, unityscript

I created car game. I have 3 checkpoint. Car refresh when I press R key
but car wrong position.

My Code;

Checkpoint.js;

```
#pragma strict

var SpawnPoint : Transform;


function OnTriggerEnter(col: Collider)
{
    if(col.tag =="Player")
    {
        SpawnPoint.position = Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y,   transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

ReSpawn.js;

```
#pragma strict
var SpawnPoint : Transform;
var player : GameObject;
var target : Transform;

function Update()
{   

if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
    {
        player.transform.position  = SpawnPoint.position;  
    }
}
```

How to force correct position?

Answer (score 0):

you should use getcomponent to get a var in another script assign your checkpoint script to var script via inspector.

```
#pragma strict
var script : Checkpoint;
var player : GameObject;
var target : Transform;

function Update()
{

if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
    {
        player.transform.position  = script.GetComponent(Checkpoint).SpawnPoint.position; 
    }
}
```